# Demoted by two(ranking)

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Let's say my hometown used to be the number 1 in terms of cleanliness, but now we are third in ranking. Then I say:

> "We're not number 1 anymore, we **got demoted by 2** and now in number 3 in ranking."

Or

> "We're not number 1 anymore, we **went down by 2** and now in number 3 in ranking."

Are these a correct phrasing?

Comment: I would say, "we were [downgraded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downgrade) by two."

Answer (score 2):

I would say the second option makes more sense than the first.  Demoted is generally something that happens as a direct punishment for an action.  Personally, I would phrase it as:

> We're not number 1 anymore.  We dropped two spots to number 3.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit, but I think that the word "two" should be spelled out, to avoid confusion between the ranking spots (1 and 3), and the number of spots that were dropped.

Answer (score 1):

"We're not number 1 anymore.  We were demoted by two, and *are* now in number 3 ranking."

J.R. is correct that spelling out the number 2 helps to avoid confusion.  Your sentence is a run-on sentence and should be separated.  The comma is required to show two separate thoughts joined in a single sentence, and the "are" is required to be grammatically correct to show your new state of being.

Comment: Oh wow thx so much for the grammar tip there! That's a top notch advice hehe

Comment: Also, what if your ''we were demoted by two'' is changed into the prev. ''We got demoted by two''?

Comment: It's acceptable.  Got is just a bit more informal in English.  I prefer a more formal approach unless I'm trying to be more relaxed and casual in my writing.  It's really just preference.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The often used phrasing to describe rankings is:

> John Arvin's #1 hometown **fell** two spots this week to number 3.
>   Whereas #2 and #3 each **gained** a spot in this week's rankings.